# Android- Old Facebook style Menu UI

Tags: android, xml, facebook, gridview, user-interface

I am looking for ways to implement and design the old style facebook UI (Not the sliding one ,but the one which looks similar to a gridlayout)

Here are some of the pictures in case you can't recollect.

http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&docid=UHkgljE_6dGpAM&tbnid=KpVp44wJ2ncUCM:&ved=&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhowto.cnet.com%2F8301-11310_39-20070840-285%2Fhow-to-unlink-facebook-for-android-from-phone-contacts%2F&ei=naRnUdXjDMLjlAXixoCgDQ&bvm=bv.45175338,d.dGI&psig=AFQjCNGxtmBmlabfaeqhL6n8zRT5zsd54Q&ust=1365833245819990

http://www.geeknewscentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/android-facebook-1.6-old-menu.png

I guess the right way is to use grid layout, but there is a catch, I want that this menu is switch able, I mean it shouldn't cover the entire screen but only some part (I need a 3*3 gridlayout).

Any way or xml code to go around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure-  use a gridLayout.  Put it in a RelativeLayout, and make sure it has android:layout_above on it for whatever element you want below it.  That will force it to stop at that view, rather than grabbing the rest of the screen.  You don't need to worry about the horizontal component because GridView is only greedy vertically I believe.  But even if I'm wrong,t he same trick would work with layout_toLeftOf and toRightOf.